# block request from/to google.com to/from my server

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-firewall

I have a Windows server 2008 and I have launched a website on it.

when my website open in Chrome browser by anyone , Chrome In addition to opening the website, it also sends my website information to Google servers.

I want no information from my website to be sent to Google servers also If Google servers send requests to my server, all of them will be blocked.

I search on the internet and i can block only IP in windows firewall , but google has hundreds IP address's .

I want block  : `*.google.com/*` inbound and outbound .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of Chrome, You can't do anything. If you are concerned about what Chrome does, you have to remember that chrome isn't running on your server, its running on the remote users device, and you cannot place a firewall between the user's location and google services or otherwise instruct the browser on what it is or isn't allowed to do, unless your users are on a network you can effectively isolate.

For your website, I'd suggest you look into a blocklist service for your firewall. Let someone else go to all the trouble of maintaining the list of google related IPs. we don't suggest products or services on this site, but I'm sure you can find something.